# CommandLineJobRunner exit status on command stop

Tags: spring-batch, exit-code

I'm working on SpringBatch using .bat and .sh.
When I use the -stop flag, I'm thought I should wait for a non zero exit code if the job doesn't exist or isn't running.
In reality, I get 0 if the job ended without error.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `CommandLineJobRunner` to stop a job, what you're really doing is making a request to stop a job.  The `CommandLineJobRunner` returns once the request is made, not once the job stops because that could be an indeterminate amount of time.  The only way you'd get a non-zero return code using the `CommandLineJobRunner` to stop a job is if the job isn't running (or can't be found in the `JobRepository`).

Comment: Okay, I understand the behavior, but in my case the job is properly ended. (Mark as COMPLETED in database). In this case, why "-stop" return me 0?

Comment: `CommandLineJobRunner` should return 0 if it found the job to stop.  Is that not what you are seeing?  The only caveat is that it's not going to wait until the job repository is marked `COMPLETED` to return.

Comment: Ok, i'm dummy, I don't was running the correct file